# How to understand "All most suspicious" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "Ariana was delicate!" said Doge desperately. "Her health was always too poor to permit her -"
>
> "To permit her to leave the house?" cackled Muriel. "And yet she was never taken to St Mungo's and no healer was ever summoned to see her!"
>
> "Really, Muriel, how you can possibly know whether -"
>
> "For your information, Elphias, my cousin Lancelot was a healer at St Mungo's at the time, and he told my family in strictest confidence that Ariana had never been seen there. **All most suspicious**, Lancelot thought!"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I have a hard time to understand "*All most suspicious*" in this context. "*All most*" doesn't look a correct phrasing. How should we understand it?

Comment: I am guessing: "All (_is_) most suspicious". "Everything about this is most suspicious."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All most suspicious"

The subject here is "all". "All" is used as a noun, meaning "everything", or "all [of the information you just told me]".

"Most" is a (kind of old fashioned) way of saying "very" or "quite" (it's an adverb).

Suspicious is an adjective used in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspicious)'s sense 1: "tending to arouse suspicion". (Example: "We thought he might be a criminal because of his **suspicious** behavior.")

The verb ("is") has been left out of the "sentence", so the whole phrase is very compact and idiomatic, but I guess that might be appropriate to describe someone's inner thoughts.

It just means that all the statements about Ariana sound contradictory and are causing suspicion in the mind of the listener. (Lancelot?... or is it Elphias?)